# SQL select multiple distinct records from one Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, greatest-n-per-group

I've a Table as below

```
ID  |FromId |ToId   |Message|DateTime
------------------------------------------
1   |1      |2      |a      |15:00
2   |1      |2      |b      |15:01
3   |1      |2      |c      |15:02
4   |2      |1      |d      |15:03
5   |3      |1      |e      |15:04
6   |3      |1      |f      |15:05
7   |1      |3      |g      |15:06
```

what I want  to get  is Every last message of Peers.

**For example:** User 1 and user 2 has 4 messages (ID:1,2,3,4) and user 1 and user 3 has 3 messages (ID:5,6,7)

I want to get only latest Message record from users, I need a SQL query which will give the result like this:

```
*sql code here ? -- I need this.
```

result (for: where UserID=1) :

```
ID  |FromId |ToId   |Message|DateTime
------------------------------------------
4   |2      |1      |d      |15:03
7   |1      |3      |g      |15:06
```

Any Ideas ? I've tried with Distinct etc. but it didn't worked somehow.  Please help.

**Sorry Guys I guess I  forgot to mention that I need the latest record from Peer, not the latest record from one user, for example for user 1 and user 2 I need the latest record from them, no mather which one is From or which one is To.. I need the latest record from both which is ID 4 in our case no other records.**

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Sql Server 2005+, you might use [row_number() over ( ... )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to group, order and number records, and then retrieve only the ones being first in their group:

```
; with cte as
(
  select *,
      -- Group by user not being searched for
         row_number() over (partition by case when FromID = @UserID
                                              then ToID
                                              else FromID
                                          end
      -- Last date will be numbered as 1
                            order by [DateTime] desc
                           ) rn
    from Table1
-- Filter only messages sent from or received by certain user
   where (FromID = @UserID or ToID = @UserID)
)
select *
  from cte
-- Get last dates only
 where rn = 1
```

Comment: I think he want a result set for all users, not one specific user, not sure though.

Comment: @Nikola thanks for your answer. I think this will be the best solution.

Comment: @adnanturken My bad, your data sample doesn't show any row outside the filtered scope so I thought you wanted all users.

Comment: :D actually my mistake let me fix the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this Sql for this:

```
Declare @tempTeable Table
(
 Id int,
 FromID int,
 ToId int,
 SMessage nvarchar(250),
 SDateTime Time 
)

Insert into @tempTeable values(1,1,2,'a','15:00')
Insert into @tempTeable values(2,1,2,'b','15:01')
Insert into @tempTeable values(3,1,2,'c','15:02')
Insert into @tempTeable values(4,2,1,'d','15:03')
Insert into @tempTeable values(5,3,1,'e','15:04')
Insert into @tempTeable values(6,3,1,'f','15:05')
Insert into @tempTeable values(7,1,3,'g','15:06')

select distinct t1.* from @tempTeable as t1
inner join 
  (select UserID,MAX(SDateTime)as SDateTime from
    (
      select FromId as UserId ,MAX(SDateTime)as SDateTime from  @tempTeable group by 
       FromId
       UNION
       select ToId as UserId,MAX(SDateTime)as SDateTime from  @tempTeable group by   
        ToId) as tbl
        group by UserId) as tblres 
  on (t1.FromID =tblres.UserId  or t1.toId =tblres.UserId) 
  and t1.SDateTime=tblres.SDateTime
```

Comment: Works perfectly but cost around 5 times more than the CTE version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a self-referential join, so the inner query selects the max per group, and the outer query selects all the data for each row that matches.

```
select * 
from thetable t1 
join(select max(ID) as id,
            FromID 
     from thetable
     group by FromID)t2 on (t1.id=t2.id);
```

Comment: this is ok but it gets only latest message from user I need latest message from Peer

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Msgs (ID int primary key, FromId int, ToId int, Message nvarchar(MAX), DateTime time);
insert into Msgs (ID, FromId, ToId, Message, Datetime) values (1   ,1      ,2      ,'a'      ,'15:00');
insert into Msgs (ID, FromId, ToId, Message, Datetime) values (2   ,1      ,2      ,'b'      ,'15:01');
insert into Msgs (ID, FromId, ToId, Message, Datetime) values (3   ,1      ,2      ,'c'      ,'15:02');
insert into Msgs (ID, FromId, ToId, Message, Datetime) values (4   ,2      ,1      ,'d'      ,'15:03');
insert into Msgs (ID, FromId, ToId, Message, Datetime) values (5   ,3      ,1      ,'e'      ,'15:04');
insert into Msgs (ID, FromId, ToId, Message, Datetime) values (6   ,3      ,1      ,'f'      ,'15:05');
insert into Msgs (ID, FromId, ToId, Message, Datetime) values (7   ,1      ,3      ,'g'      ,'15:06');
select * from Msgs;

with M(ID, FromId, ToId, Message, DateTime, RN) as (
select ID, FromId, ToId, Message, DateTime,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by 
        CASE WHEN FromId < ToID THEN FromId ELSE ToID END, 
        CASE WHEN FromId > ToID THEN FromId ELSE ToID END 
        order by DateTime desc)
from Msgs)
select ID, FromId, ToId, Message, DateTime from M where RN = 1;

drop table Msgs;
```

Returns

```
ID  FromId  ToId    Message DateTime
1   1   2   a   15:00:00.0000000
2   1   2   b   15:01:00.0000000
3   1   2   c   15:02:00.0000000
4   2   1   d   15:03:00.0000000
5   3   1   e   15:04:00.0000000
6   3   1   f   15:05:00.0000000
7   1   3   g   15:06:00.0000000

ID  FromId  ToId    Message DateTime
4   2   1   d   15:03:00.0000000
7   1   3   g   15:06:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
;WITH CTE As(
select id,fromID,ToID,Message,DateTime,0 as sel from Msgs where id=1
union all
select m.id,m.fromID,m.ToID,m.Message,m.DateTime,
CASE WHEN (m.FromId =c.FromId or m.FromId =c.ToId) then 0 else 1 end as sel 
from CTE c inner join Msgs m 
--on (c.FromId = m.FromId and c.ToId = m.ToId) or (c.FromId = m.ToId and c.ToId = m.FromId)
on m.id=c.Id+1
)

select * from CTE where ID in (select ID-1 from CTE where sel=1)
union
select * from CTE where ID = (select max(id) from CTE)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
create function getlastmessage(
@userid int
)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
select top(1), message from messages 
 where userid=@userid order by messageid desc
```

in the people table

```
select *, getlastmessage(actorid) as lastmessage from people
```

[More info about function syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

---

if you don't want to use functions

```
select 
*, 
(select top(1), message from messages 
  where messages.userid=people.userid order by messageid desc) as lastmessage 
 from people
```

it will be a bit messy.

Comment: using a function will work, but you end up doing an extra query for each distinct fromid in the table...

Comment: Would you rather do two queries and let the server do a join on indexes between two tables or have N queries run where N is the number of distinct IDs in the database.. You will hit scaling problems as time goes on.

Comment: @Stephen the select (max) in your second query already does that N times. so you're technically doing the same job on a different query and doing a join in addition to that.

Comment: The difference is that I'm collecting the data once and then doing a join..  Using a function requires you to do an entire new query for each row...

Comment: @Stephen the problem is, when you're collecting the data with the group by, the execution applies the same steps.

Comment: There is alot more internal overhead within the server to create a new query than to let the join buffer do its job.. Try it on 40,000,000 rows and see which is faster...

Comment: @Stephen http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/ea45f245-980c-4212-a1bc-3912267b3055

Comment: @Stephen http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx this is from MSDN documentation.

Comment: @ugrcode A subquery is different from a temporary table.. Subquery will run each time as well.  Joining against a temporary table like above will run once..

Comment: @Stephen that's what you believe and not how the queries work. I gave reference to MSDN. the discussion is already over.

Comment: @ugrcode - Its the difference between "subselect" and "derived table".  We're not talking about the same thing.

Comment: Also, you said "select (max) in your second query already does that N times".  In order to pick up the max of every type in the table it does not need to do N queries, It can do it in 1 table scan.  Thats the point behind generating a derived table.